# No carga matriz para animacion

Tags: c#, windows-forms

El control tiene transparencia, y necesito seguir manteniendola. Esta es la parte del codigo que debería mostrar el arreglo, pero no lo muestra.
La pagina no me deja cargar el codigo completo, o bien yo no se hacerlo!!! Si alguien me enseña subo el codigo completo!!!

```
   public class ControlTranspa : Control
   {
       private readonly Timer refresher;
       private Image _image;
       private Timer TmrAnima = new Timer();
       private System.ComponentModel.IContainer components;
       private PictureBox Box4 = new PictureBox();
       private Image[] Imagenes = new Image[16];
       private int counter = 1;
       public ControlTranspa()
       {
           SetStyle(ControlStyles.SupportsTransparentBackColor, true);
           BackColor = Color.Transparent;
           //PictureBoxSizeMode.StretchImage = true;
           refresher = new Timer();
           refresher.Tick += TimerOnTick;
           refresher.Interval = 50;
           refresher.Enabled = true;
           refresher.Start();
       }
       #region "PARA CREAR LA TRANSPARENCIA DEL CONTROL"
       protected override CreateParams CreateParams
       {
           get
           {
               CreateParams cp = base.CreateParams;
               cp.ExStyle |= 0x20;
               return cp;
           }
       }
   protected override void OnMove(EventArgs e)
   {
       RecreateHandle();
   }

   protected override void OnPaint(PaintEventArgs e)
   {
       if (_image != null)
       {
           //e.Graphics.DrawImage(_image, (Width / 4) - (_image.Width / 4), (Height / 4) - (_image.Height / 4));
           e.Graphics.DrawImage(Imagenes[counter], 0, 0, Width, Height);   //(_image.Width/ 4), (_image.Height / 4));
       }
   }
   protected override void OnPaintBackground(PaintEventArgs e)
   {
       //No pintar el fondo
   }
       #endregion
```

```
       #region "PARA MOSTRAR LAS IMAGENES DEL CONTROL"
       private void CargarImgs()
       {
           Imagenes[0] = LineasAnimadasOtrasYerbas.Properties.Resources.rot;
           Imagenes[1] = LineasAnimadasOtrasYerbas.Properties.Resources.rot1;
           Imagenes[2] = LineasAnimadasOtrasYerbas.Properties.Resources.rot2;
           Imagenes[3] = LineasAnimadasOtrasYerbas.Properties.Resources.rot3;
           Imagenes[4] = LineasAnimadasOtrasYerbas.Properties.Resources.rot4;
           Imagenes[5] = LineasAnimadasOtrasYerbas.Properties.Resources.rot5;
           Imagenes[6] = LineasAnimadasOtrasYerbas.Properties.Resources.rot6;
           Imagenes[7] = LineasAnimadasOtrasYerbas.Properties.Resources.rot7;
           Imagenes[8] = LineasAnimadasOtrasYerbas.Properties.Resources.rot8;
           Imagenes[9] = LineasAnimadasOtrasYerbas.Properties.Resources.rot9;
           Imagenes[10] = LineasAnimadasOtrasYerbas.Properties.Resources.rot10;
           Imagenes[11] = LineasAnimadasOtrasYerbas.Properties.Resources.rot11;
           Imagenes[12] = LineasAnimadasOtrasYerbas.Properties.Resources.rot12;
           Imagenes[13] = LineasAnimadasOtrasYerbas.Properties.Resources.rot13;
           Imagenes[14] = LineasAnimadasOtrasYerbas.Properties.Resources.rot14;
           Imagenes[15] = LineasAnimadasOtrasYerbas.Properties.Resources.rot15;
       }
   }

//Agregado código publicado por el op como comentario

   private void TmrAnima_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e) 
   { 
      TmrAnima.Interval = Intervalo; 
    // Convert.ToInt32(updDelay.Value); 
   //.Value.ToString(); 
     if (counter >= 15) 
     { 
        // Sale del bucle. 
        counter = 1; 
      } 
    else 
     { // Incrementa el contador de reproducción. 
     counter = counter + 1; 
     Image = Imagenes[counter]; 
     //Box4.Image = Imagenes[counter]; 
     }  
   }
```

Comment: No veo tu evento TimerOnTick, que es donde deberia estar tu logica, me parece

Comment: Aqui va el codigo del TimerTick       private void TmrAnima_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        TmrAnima.Interval = Intervalo;   // Convert.ToInt32(updDelay.Value);  //.Value.ToString();
        if (counter >= 15)
        {
            // Sale del bucle.  
            counter = 1;
        }
        else
        {
            // Incrementa el contador de reproducción.  
            counter = counter + 1;
            Image = Imagenes[counter];
            //Box4.Image = Imagenes[counter];
        }
    }

Comment: Hola @RamiroBarone, un consejo, cuando edites agregando código que el op agregó como comentario (lo cual no está mal), agrega en el comentario de edición algo como "Agregado código publicado por el op como comentario". Lo digo porque vengo de la cola de revisión (no aparecen los comentarios) y he estado a punto de rechazar por "atentado" sobre la publicación tu edición. Un saludo.

Comment: @FJSevilla lo tengo en cuenta. Gracias

Comment: @Fabian recuerda que puedes añadir la info editando la pregunta con el enlace `editar` que está justo debajo. Con eso, si tienes código adicional, lo puedes poner allí en vez de en un comentario.

Comment: Hola @RamiroBarone, el control no muestra las imágenes, puedo cargar en el arreglo, pero sigue sin mostrarlas, Pienso que el problema esta en la aplicación de la clase System.Drawing que yo no estoy aplicando correctamente, especificamente en:   protected override void OnPaint(PaintEventArgs e)
   {
       if (_image != null)
       {
           //e.Graphics.DrawImage(_image, (Width / 4) - (_image.Width / 4), (Height / 4) - (_image.Height / 4));
           e.Graphics.DrawImage(Imagenes[counter], 0, 0, Width, Height);   //(_image.Width/ 4), (_image.Height / 4));
       }
   }   --AYUDA!!